# Angular Directive not updating element using interval

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have this directive

```
angular.module('mydirectives').directive('slideShow', function ($interval) {
return{
    scope:{slideShow:'=slideShow'},
    link:function(scope, element, attrs){         

        element.css("background-size","cover");
        element.css("background-repeat","none");
        element.css("background-position","center center");
        element.css("background-blend-mode","color");
        element.css("background-color","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)");

        scope.index=0;

        function nextSlide()
        {
            if(!scope.slideShow) return;
            if(scope.slideShow.sources.length===0) return;

            var url=scope.slideShow.sources[scope.index++];
            if(scope.index>=scope.slideShow.sources.length) scope.index=0;

            element.css({'background-image': 'url(' + url +')'});
        }

        nextSlide();
        var interval= $interval(nextSlide,3000)
        scope.$on("$destroy",function(){
            $interval.cancel(interval);
        })
    }
}
});
```

this is how i apply it

```
<section class="primary" slide-show="slideShow">
```

now the controller which provides property "slideShow" gets the value via http request. when it comes back with response it sets the value of slideShow like this

```
$scope.slideShow={sources:["http:\\sources\someimage.jgp"]}  
webApi.getHomePageModel().then(function(model){
   $scope.model=model;
   $scope.slideShow=model.slideShow;        
},function(error){
   console.dir(error);
});
```

**The Problem**: when this runs only the default value of slideshow works and element's background-image is set but after the response to http the new value is set to slideShow but the when interval function "nextSlide" executes then background-image is not updated. in debugger i can see the url values is being picked up correctly but element is not updated.

**EDIT**:I was making a stupid mistake, the updated model was not as expected the elements in sources were not strings as expected (they were being generated as complex objects rather than string value.) all working now. also no need for scope.$applyAsync because the $interval service handles that for you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using setInterval then you need to manually rerun angular's digetst cycle:

```
function nextSlide()
    {
        if(!scope.slideShow) return;
        if(scope.slideShow.sources.length===0) return;

        var url=scope.slideShow.sources[scope.index++];
        if(scope.index>=scope.slideShow.sources.length) scope.index=0;

        element.css({'background-image': 'url(' + url +')'});

        scope.applyAsync();  //this line!
        //May not work in older angular versions, if such you should use scope.apply()

    }
```

Comment: tried it "scope.$applyAsync()" does not do anything. and scope.$apply throws inprog error. and i tried another thing. i replaced the html with url value and what i saw was it shows first url i.e. from hardcoded model but then on first interval it clears the html value and shows nothing. could there be something to do with the scope of variables

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this implementation

```
angular.module('app').directive('slideShow', function ($interval) {
return{
    scope:{slideShow:'=slideShow'},
    link:function(scope, element, attrs){         
        var index=0;


        function nextSlide()
        {
            if(!scope.slideShow) return;
            if(scope.slideShow.images.length===0) return;

            var url=scope.slideShow.images[index++];
            if(index>=scope.slideShow.images.length) index=0;               
            element.css({'background-image': 'url(' + url +')'});
        }

        var interval=false;
        var watchSlideShow=scope.$watch("slideShow",function(){
            if(!scope.slideShow) return;
            if(scope.slideShow.images.length===0) return;
            if(interval) return;

            nextSlide();
            var interval= $interval(nextSlide,5000);
        });

        scope.$on("$destroy",function(){
            $interval.cancel(interval);
            watchSlideShow();
        });
    }
}
});
```